# Call ProgressDialog loader in fragment when service is finished

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-cloud-messaging

I have a specific situation with my fragment. It's settings fragment where user can choose to enable or disable push notifications. If he choose to enable push notifications this is happening:

```
 getActivity().startService(new      Intent(getActivity(),RegistrationIntentService.class));
```

RegistrationIntentService.class is class from GCM tutorial modified to send my details and register app within GCM. How can I now create something so that I can show users ProgressBar until that service execute. So basicly flow is like this:

- User press button to enable notificatons in app from fragment
- Progress bar start spinning in fragment and service is running in background
- When service is complete (user is registered) progressbar.dismiss() happen

Answer (score 1):

From the tutorial:

> A declaration of GcmReceiver, which handles messages sent from GCM to your application.

It's up to you to decide how to do this when your `BroadcastReceiver` receives the broadcast `Intent` from GCM with the action `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` or `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` (pre-4.4 KitKat devices.)  A simple way would be to use a `Handler` and message to have your receiver send the `Fragment` or `Activity` a message.